# Export to Excel from SQL server through BCP

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, bcp

I tried to export the result of a query to an excel sheet with the following BCP command and I was successful.

But the issue is, one of the columns have data with delimiter. Because of that the structure of the data is affected when I open the file in MS Excel. The data is not coming in the desired cell.

Is there anyway to escape the delimiter in the data of the column.

```
set @cmd='bcp "select ''colName1'',''colName2'',''colName3'',''colName4'',''colName5'',''colName6'',''colName7'' union all SELECT colValue1,colValue2,CONVERT(varchar,[colValue3]),[colValue4],convert(varchar,[colValue5]),[colValue6],[colValue7] from [DBName].[dbo].[ViewName] where  [colValue5]='''+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE()-1, 112)+'''" queryout "HYPERLINK "D:\Report_'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112)+'.xls"D:\Reports\Detailed_Comment_Report_'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)+'.xls" -c -T -t -S ABCD'
```

Comment: Double quote each data field.

Comment: This won't create an Excel file. It creates a CSV with an .xls extension. You should use SSIS to export.

Comment: Why not change the delimiter.  Try comma for example by following the "-t" switch with a comma like this:  -t,

Comment: @kevin horgan - I tried that but the column contains , ; |. So the same old story again :(